# debug java application while startup

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

It might sound a bit too naive, but I always had a tough time to debug a java class during server startup. Here is the scenario:

- The java application is hosted on a tomcat server.
- Suppose there is a class which is invoked while the tomcat server starts up.
- As soon as I stop the tomcat instance for a restart, the eclipse debug stops and I can start the debug only once the application is up and running.
- Now how do I debug this class on eclipse?

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Put a break point where do you want to debug in your class and make sure to start the server in debug mode.

Comment: I do the same. But in order to start the debugging on eclipse, the server should be up and running, right? Until then when I click on the debug symbol, it throws an error. And by the time it starts working, the class is already invoked and I am missing it.

Answer (score 16):

You need to pass the "wait for debugger to connect" flag to tomcat. So the startup will wait until you have connected and thus you won't miss the breakpoint.

Take for example those java options to make tomcat listen for a debugger:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8797,server=y,suspend=y
```

The wait for a debugger connection flag is the `suspend=y` entry in the above line.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging of classes during startup should work without problems. For example, suppose you implement a [ServletContextListener class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). The belonging contextInitialized method is called during Tomcat startup (or to be more precise: while your app gets deployed).

You can set breakpoints in this class. At that point, Tomcat is already started completely and there shouldn't be any problems with debugging.

Comment: Hey Sebi,
I can surely set the breakpoints. But for the breakpoints to work, the debug on my eclipse should run ... and my problem is that the debug doesn't run on my eclipse until the server is completely up and running.

Comment: Try an external server not started by eclipse using remote debugging. You can start that server before deploying your app on it. Afterwards, you deploy your app via eclipse while you are already connected to the server. If your breakpoints are still ignored, try a simple test app first.

Comment: I usually do not start my server through eclipse. I start the tomcat server ( of course the custom startup script ) and then hook eclipse debug option using the localhost and the debug port number.